# How do I use the For loop in Firebird?

Tags: sql, for-loop, firebird

Can someone explain to me the syntax of the `For` loop in Firebird?

Here is the code I have so far:

```
As 
Declare variable Var1 integer;
begin
Insert into table1 
-- Select query to insert some enteries in table 1 - Done successfully.
FOR SELECT table1.Column1 from table1 into :Var1 
Do
Begin 
Update tableabc.column1 = (select tablexyz. column1 from tablexyz where tablexyz.ID = :Var1) where tableabc.ID = :Var1 
End
```

Update : Thanks for giving it a try but i dont see any major difference between the query that i wrote and query included in answers. Although above query runs successfully at my end but when i see data in table there occurs no update.

Actually i was making a v.dumb mistake, i was executing alter stored procedure query - which runs successfully and i was assuming this would make the necessary changes. later i executed the stored procedure and it worked pefectly . Thanks all for sparing your time :) ..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**For** operator in Firebird is not like **For**, say, in Pascal where it increments loop variable and executes a block of code until finish value will be met.

In Firebird **For** operator takes a set of records (result of execution of a query) and loops through them. For every record a block of code will be executed. Optionally values of some fields from the record could be put into local variables enlisted in **INTO** section. Values of such variables could be used inside a block of code.

In your example a query:

```
SELECT table1.Column1 from table1 into :Var1
```

Will be executed and for every record in result set will be executed operator:

```
Update tableabc.column1 = 
  (select tablexyz. column1 from tablexyz where tablexyz.ID = :Var1) 
where tableabc.ID = :Var1
```

For it variable :Var will contain value of table1.Column1 of current record.

Answer (score 2):

```
create procedure TEST
as
declare variable TMP integer;
begin
  for select one_f from one into :tmp
  do
  begin
      insert into two (two_f) values (:tmp); 
  end
  suspend;
end
```

For each row in table "one" execute the operator insert.
Tmp contains value of current row from table "one".

P.S. sorry for my english